# Как сделать, чтобы анимацию нельзя было прекратить?

Tags: unity3d

Как сделать, чтобы анимацию нельзя было прекратить? У меня есть анимация смерти и на последнем кадре игрок уничтожается со сцены, но из этой анимации можно перейти в другую и тем самым до последнего кадра не доходит и игрок не удаляется.

[image: Animator]

[image: Transition -> Death]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можно использовать [параметры аниматора](https://docs.unity3d.com/2019.4/Documentation/Manual/AnimationParameters.html).

Создаем новый параметр с именем **IsLive** типа **bool** со значением по умолчанию **true**.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

При смерти нам будет необходимо поменять значение этого параметра на **false**.
Можно сделать таким образом:

- Выбираем стейт **Death**
- Щелкаем по **AddBehavior**
- Добавляем такой скрипт

```
using UnityEngine;

public class Death : StateMachineBehaviour
{
    override public void OnStateEnter(Animator animator, AnimatorStateInfo stateInfo, int layerIndex)
    {
        animator.SetBool("IsLive",false);
    }

}
```

Если у вас есть метод смерти где-то в другом месте, вы можете прописать `animator.SetBool("IsLive",false);` там, предварительно сохранив ссылку на нужный **Animator** где-нибудь в старте.

Ну и дальше для всех ваших переходов из **AnyState** просто добавляем условие **IsLive** == **true**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: С одной стороны, так легко, а с другой - я не додумался, спасибо.